# PHPUnit: How to test the downloading of a file with Guzzle

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, file-upload, phpunit

I'm trying to write a functional test for a Symfony2 controller which uses an Image entity that, using `\GuzzleHttp\Client`, downloads an image from a remote URL and stores it on the local filesystem. Then the entity is used to persist in the database the information about the downloaded image.

The method is this and is taken, with some changes, from the [Symfony documentation about how to upload a file](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#basic-setup), where it is called `upload()`.

I've done some editings, as the signature, where a client is required to be passed (to decouple the class from the client to be able to unit test it).

```
/**
 * @param Client $client The client to use to download the image
 */
public function download(Client $client)
{
    // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
    $this->path = $this->getDownloadDir();

    // Get the remote file extension
    $remoteImageExtension = explode('.', $this->getRemoteUri()->getPath());
    $remoteImageExtension = array_pop($remoteImageExtension);
    $fs = new Filesystem();

    $tempImage = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image.') . '.' . $remoteImageExtension;

    // Get and save file
    $client->get($this->getRemoteUri(), ['save_to' => $tempImage]);

    $tempImage = new File($tempImage);

    $this->name = $this->getName() . '.' . $remoteImageExtension;
    $newImage = $this->getDownloadRootDir() . $this->getName();

    $fs->copy($tempImage, $newImage);
}
```

As you can see the method uses the client to download the image and save it to a local temp folder.

**My question is: which file should have I to pass to the client?**

In my tests I mock the `GuzzleHttp\Client` class and set the method `$client->get()` to return simply `true`.

But the entity throws an exception, because it makes use of `File` that requires a real file passed (download from the remote URL).

So, I think I have to pass the URL of a real remote file, but doing so seems to me something to avoid.

How can I test this method?

I've also tried to use a temp image in this way:

```
    $image = new Image();

    $mockClient = $this->getMockBuilder('\GuzzleHttp\Client')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $mockClient->method('get')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));

    $mockUri = $this->getMockBuilder('\SerendipityHQ\Framework\ValueObjects\Uri\Uri')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $fakeRemoteUri = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image') . '.jpg';
    $mockUri->method('getPath')
            ->will($this->returnValue($fakeRemoteUri));

    $image->setName(rand(0, 100))
        ->setCreatedOn(new \DateTime())
        ->setModifiedOn(new \DateTime())
        ->setRemoteUri($mockUri)
        ->setDownloadDir('path/to/download')
        ->download($mockClient);
```

This returns me:

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException:
>   The file
>   "/private/var/folders/s5/wwsxvmxd025ctwf0ywwqf83c0000gn/T/image.NW4jvT./private/var/folders/s5/wwsxvmxd025ctwf0ywwqf83c0000gn/T/imagemf9ZPrjpg"
>   does not exist